# Is the quoting behavior of KSQL changed since version 5.1.3?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Ksql request, I tried to escape the column which should be lower case "operator_id", here's what I've got.

```
{"ksql": "CREATE STREAM stream1 WITH (PARTITIONS=4, REPLICAS=1, KAFKA_TOPIC='stream1_topic', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO') AS SELECT * FROM TestMessagePingPong_AVRO_STREAM WHERE \"operator_id\" = 1154;","streamsProperties":{"ksql.streams.auto.offset.reset":"latest"}}
```

this gives me

```
"message": "io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlStatementException: Field 'TESTMESSAGEPINGPONG_AVRO_STREAM.OPERATOR_ID' cannot be resolved.
```

version Ksql server version 5.4.0

It worked before while I was on the version 5.1.3.

Description of the source stream:

```
{"ksql": "describe TestMessagePingPong_AVRO_STREAM;","streamsProperties":{"ksql.streams.auto.offset.reset":"latest"}}

[{"@type":"sourceDescription","statementText":"describe TestMessagePingPong_AVRO_STREAM;","sourceDescription":{"name":"TESTMESSAGEPINGPONG_AVRO_STREAM","readQueries":[],"writeQueries":[{"sinks":["TESTMESSAGEPINGPONG_AVRO_STREAM"],"id":"CSAS_TESTMESSAGEPINGPONG_AVRO_STREAM_15","queryString":"CREATE STREAM TESTMESSAGEPINGPONG_AVRO_STREAM WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='TestMessagePingPongAvro', PARTITIONS=4, REPLICAS=1, VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO') AS SELECT\n TESTMESSAGEPINGPONG_JSON_STREAM.OPERATORID \"operator_id\",\n TESTMESSAGEPINGPONG_JSON_STREAM.ID \"id\"\nFROM TESTMESSAGEPINGPONG_JSON_STREAM TESTMESSAGEPINGPONG_JSON_STREAM\nEMIT CHANGES;"}],"fields":[{"name":"ROWTIME","schema":{"type":"BIGINT","fields":null,"memberSchema":null}},{"name":"ROWKEY","schema":{"type":"STRING","fields":null,"memberSchema":null}},{"name":"operator_id","schema":{"type":"BIGINT","fields":null,"memberSchema":null}},{"name":"id","schema":{"type":"STRING","fields":null,"memberSchema":null}}],"type":"STREAM","key":"","timestamp":"","statistics":"","errorStats":"","extended":false,"format":"AVRO","topic":"TestMessagePingPongAvro","partitions":0,"replication":0},"warnings":[]}]
```

It seems to be related to this feature:
https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/pull/2545

Comment: There is lots of work underway with quoted identifiers in KSQL. I'd suggest following this query up on the issue you note, or the ksqldb-dev channel on http://cnfl.io/slack

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what changed in the quoting behaviour, or if it was intentional or not, but the [docs](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/concepts/schemas/#valid-identifiers) say you should be using back-ticks to quote identifiers, so your query should be:

```
{"ksql": "CREATE STREAM stream1 WITH (PARTITIONS=4, REPLICAS=1, KAFKA_TOPIC='stream1_topic', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO') AS SELECT * FROM TestMessagePingPong_AVRO_STREAM WHERE `operator_id` = 1154;","streamsProperties":{"ksql.streams.auto.offset.reset":"latest"}}
```